# Reference Request: Eager for more after Chapter on Modules in Lang's Algebra

Tags: reference-request

After about six months of study (over the course of about 16 months total) I’m coming to the end of Ch. 3 (on modules) in Lang’s Algebra (third edition) and I don’t know if it’s the high I’m feeling now that I actually feel pretty comfortable with the content, and am making connections between different parts of the book, and am actually understanding what he’s writing and why it’s significant (generally feeling that I’ve mathematically matured a lot in the 150ish pages it’s taken me to get this far) but I’m a bit jittery for higher peaks, and I’m curious to know what advantages or disadvantages there might be in going on to any one of the following at the end of the chapter:

Going on to Ch. 4 in Lang, on polynomials, and then on to Galois Theory

Going to part 3 in Lang, on Representation Theory

Complex Made Simple

Galois Groups and Fundamental Groups

Topology: A Categorical Approach

Topology and Groupoids

Gunning's books on Holomorphic Functions

Something more on Ring Theory or Module Theory

Aside from the first three chapters of Lang, I studied Spivak’s Calculus up to the part on infinite series, and Lang’s Linear Algebra. I don’t have any particularly great mathematical interest right now that might make me choose one over the other, but I’ve vicariously felt the allure of Galois Theory for some time (actually the reason I began Lang), but I’d say right now, I know equally little (and am just as interested to learn) about all topics listed above. Any other suggestions are welcome of course.

Comment: Adkins and Weintraub (1992) do algebra, everything, written consistently using modules  https://www.google.com/books/edition/Algebra/RFzdBwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover

Comment: You might be interested in Eisenbud and Harris if you want to continue on in commutative algebra. Regardless, it's cool to see how enthusiastic you are about the subject.